# Connecting R to mysql DB via SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, r, rstudio

My company recently changed the method of connecting to databases.
Earlier it was 'TCP/IP' only but now it is 'TCP/IP over SSH' which uses private key to connect to the DB. I am unable to find a method which can assist me in connecting R to mysql using this new method.

Comment: try with some Tools like SQLyog or u can use putty.

Comment: But I want to connect R o mysql. I doubt that SQLyog or putty will help me.

Comment: RMySQL supports SSL: https://www.opencpu.org/posts/rmysql-release-0-10-2/. You really need to tunnel over SSH?

Comment: "TCP/IP over SSH" usually means that an SSH tunnel is being established. You use localhost/port vs remotehost/port then as your connection options. We don't have enough info to help you, though.